# Alternative to MFC Webrowser Control

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, webbrowser-control

I want to add the ability to view specific websites in my MFC application. My problem is that I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and if I use MFC's IWebBroser2, it looks like I'm stuck with using an equivalent of IE7.

My question is is there any alternatives that render html according to modern standards and that I could easily implement, or am I stuck using IE7?